# Pin to Top Functionality using orderby custom field then event date

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, order, sort, sticky-post

I need to accomplish the following:

- pull CPT tribe_events
- sort by custom field "pin_to_top" in DESC order
- get posts from today's date & any in the future
- sort remaining posts in ASC order

My goal is to keep any posts with 'pin_to_top' = 1  at the top of the results, then display the remaining results in ASC order by event date.

Here's my query:

```
$data7 = array (
'post_status' => 'publish',
// create array of arrays
'meta_query' => array(
    // pin to top array
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'pin_to_top',
        'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'meta_value_num' => '1',
        'compare' => '='
        ),
    // event start date array
    array(
        'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
        'meta_value' => '$today',
        'compare' => '>='
        ),
    ),
// custom post type
'post_type' =>
  array (
    'tribe_events' => 'tribe_events'
),
// categories of custom post type
'tribe_events_cat' => 'events',
// sorting
'orderby' => array(
    'pin_to_top' => 'DESC',
    '_EventStartDate' => 'ASC'
  ),
);
```

I am open to suggestions and please keep in mind that I'm just getting started with WP Dev. TIA

Comment: Why not using two queries? First for `pin_to_top` posts and then use the id's of those posts in second query with `post__not_in` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar aproach some days ago

```
//.....
'meta_query'      => array(
           'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'pin_clause' = array(
                'meta_key' => 'pin_to_top',
                'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'meta_value_num' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
                )
            ),
            array(
                'date_clause' => array(
                    'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
                    'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
                    'meta_value' => '$today',
                    'compare' => '>='
                )
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => array(
            'pin_clause' => 'DESC',
            'date_clause' => 'ASC'
        )
 //....
```

I don't know if I got your names right, but I think it will help to understand the trick.

Comment: I'm still unable to get this working and have setup a sandbox dev environment if anyone is willing to hep & teach me along the way. For money. 

Here's my updated query using your suggestions:

https://codeshare.io/5gY3yG

Comment: Very important in the order part: `// sorting
  'orderby' => array(
    'pin_clause' => 'DESC',
    'date_clause' => 'ASC'
   ),`